# Express modifying the response headers

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using Express to to serve some webpages. I have a font file (woff) that I'm downloading using node's https API. I then pass the response headers along to the response I'm returning to the client. The issue I have is that express seems to be modifying the response headers, specifically the `content-type` and `content-length` headers.

I'm calling res.set() and passing the headers from the server side request

Here is some code:

```
app.get('/*', (req, res, next) => {

  https.get(URI, (serversideRes) => {

    serversideRes.on('end', () => {

        res.set(serversideRes.headers);

        console.log(res.getHeaders()['content-type']);     //font/x-woff

        console.log(res.getHeaders()['content-length']);     //27756

        res.send(data);

        console.log(res.getHeaders()['content-type']);     //font/x-woff; charset=utf-8

        console.log(res.getHeaders()['content-length']);     //49574

     }
 
  }

}
```

In the browser console I'm getting

> Failed to decode downloaded font
>
> OTS parsing error: incorrect file size in WOFF header

From the [Express API](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send)

> This method performs many useful tasks for simple non-streaming responses: For example, it automatically assigns the Content-Length HTTP response header field *(unless previously defined)* and provides automatic HEAD and HTTP cache freshness support.

In this case, the headers clearly seem to be *previously defined*.